# sort a column based on the result of groupby

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, group-by

I have a dataset like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['13:30', '9:20', '18:12', '19:00', '11:20', '13:30', '15:20', '17:12', '16:00', '8:20'],
               'item': ["coffee", "bread", "pizza", "rice", "soup", "coffee", "bread", "pizza", "rice", "soup"]})
```

this is my desired output
[image]

and this is my code

```
#split the hour part from the time string
df['hour'] = df.Time.apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))

def time_period(hour):
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 11:
        return 'breakfast'
    elif hour >= 11 and hour < 15:
        return 'lunch'
    else:
        return 'dinner'
df['meal'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda x: time_period(x))

a = df.groupby(['meal','Item']).size()
l = []
for i in np.sort(a.index.get_level_values(level=0).unique().tolist()):
    l.append(a.loc[i].reset_index().rename(columns = {0:'count'}))
b = pd.concat(l,axis=1)
c = [i for i in a.index.get_level_values(level=0).unique().tolist()*2]
c = np.sort(c)
b.columns = [c,b.columns]
display(b.head(10))
```

I just want to sort the table based on breakfast count and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better code to achieve what you need is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['13:30', '9:20', '18:12', '19:00', '11:20', '13:30', 
                  '15:20', '17:12', '16:00', '8:20'],
                   'item': ["coffee", "bread", "pizza", "rice", "soup", "coffee", "bread", "pizza", "rice", "soup"]})

df['hour'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
df['meal'] = np.where((df.hour >= 6) & (df.hour < 11), 'breakfast',
                 np.where((df.hour>=11) & (df.hour < 15), 'lunch', 'dinner')) 

df = df.groupby(['meal', 
     'item']).size().rename('count').to_frame().reset_index().pivot(columns=['meal'])
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
df.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by=('breakfast', 'count'), inplace=True)
df

           breakfast        dinner        lunch   
           count   item  count   item count    item
0          1.0  bread    NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN
1          1.0   soup    NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN
2          NaN    NaN    1.0  bread   NaN     NaN
3          NaN    NaN    2.0  pizza   NaN     NaN
4          NaN    NaN    2.0   rice   NaN     NaN
5          NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   2.0  coffee
6          NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   1.0    soup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) specifying the column you want to sort by:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=
    {'time': ['13:30', '9:20', '18:12', '19:00', '11:20', '13:30', '15:20', '17:12', '16:00', '8:20'],
     'item': ["coffee", "bread", "pizza", "rice", "soup", "coffee", "bread", "pizza", "rice", "soup"]
})

#split the hour part from the time string
df['hour'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))

def time_period(hour):
    if hour >= 6 and hour < 11:
        return 'breakfast'
    elif hour >= 11 and hour < 15:
        return 'lunch'
    else:
        return 'dinner'
df['meal'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda x: time_period(x))

df[['meal', 'item']].pivot_table(columns='meal', index='item', aggfunc=np.size).sort_values('breakfast', ascending=True)

meal    breakfast   dinner  lunch
item            
bread   2.0 2.0 NaN
soup    2.0 NaN 2.0
coffee  NaN NaN 4.0
pizza   NaN 4.0 NaN
rice    NaN 4.0 NaN
```